# Roblox Fly Command

Tags: roblox

I am making my own version of admin commands called "Yourself Admin Commands" but unfortunately I broke the fly command function. Yourself Admin Commands is an admin command script made by "Frozeis" on Roblox. Does anyone have any idea how to fix the fly command? Here is the code I have got:

```
if message == "fly".. prefix and tableContains(owner, player.Name) then
    coroutine.resume(coroutine.create(function()
        if player and player:findFirstChild("PlayerGui") then
            repeat wait() until game.Players.LocalPlayer and game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character and game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character:findFirstChild("Torso") and game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character:findFirstChild("Humanoid")
            local mouse = game.Players.LocalPlayer:GetMouse()
            repeat wait() until mouse
            local plr = player
            local torso = plr.Character.Torso
            local flying = true
            local deb = true
            local ctrl = {f = 0, b = 0, l = 0, r = 0}
            local lastctrl = {f = 0, b = 0, l = 0, r = 0}
            local maxspeed = 500
            local speed = 0
            function Fly()
                local bg = Instance.new("BodyGyro", torso)
                bg.P = 9e4
                bg.maxTorque = Vector3.new(9e9, 9e9, 9e9)
                bg.cframe = torso.CFrame
                local bv = Instance.new("BodyVelocity", torso)
                bv.velocity = Vector3.new(0,0.1,0)
                bv.maxForce = Vector3.new(9e9, 9e9, 9e9)
                repeat wait()
                    player.Character.Humanoid.PlatformStand = true
                    if ctrl.l + ctrl.r ~= 0 or ctrl.f + ctrl.b ~= 0 then
                        speed = speed+.5+(speed/maxspeed)
                        if speed > maxspeed then
                            speed = maxspeed
                        end
                    elseif not (ctrl.l + ctrl.r ~= 0 or ctrl.f + ctrl.b ~= 0) and speed ~= 0 then
                        speed = speed-1
                        if speed < 0 then
                            speed = 0
                        end
                    end
                    if (ctrl.l + ctrl.r) ~= 0 or (ctrl.f + ctrl.b) ~= 0 then
                        bv.velocity = ((game.Workspace.CurrentCamera.CoordinateFrame.lookVector * (ctrl.f+ctrl.b)) + ((game.Workspace.CurrentCamera.CoordinateFrame * CFrame.new(ctrl.l+ctrl.r,(ctrl.f+ctrl.b)*.2,0).p) - game.Workspace.CurrentCamera.CoordinateFrame.p))*speed
                        lastctrl = {f = ctrl.f, b = ctrl.b, l = ctrl.l, r = ctrl.r}
                    elseif (ctrl.l + ctrl.r) == 0 and (ctrl.f + ctrl.b) == 0 and speed ~= 0 then
                        bv.velocity = ((game.Workspace.CurrentCamera.CoordinateFrame.lookVector * (lastctrl.f+lastctrl.b)) + ((game.Workspace.CurrentCamera.CoordinateFrame * CFrame.new(lastctrl.l+lastctrl.r,(lastctrl.f+lastctrl.b)*.2,0).p) - game.Workspace.CurrentCamera.CoordinateFrame.p))*speed
                    else
                        bv.velocity = Vector3.new(0,0.1,0)
                    end
                    bg.cframe = game.Workspace.CurrentCamera.CoordinateFrame * CFrame.Angles(-math.rad((ctrl.f+ctrl.b)*50*speed/maxspeed),0,0)
                until not flying
                ctrl = {f = 0, b = 0, l = 0, r = 0}
                lastctrl = {f = 0, b = 0, l = 0, r = 0}
                speed = 0
                bg:Destroy()
                bv:Destroy()
                plr.Character.Humanoid.PlatformStand = false
            end
            mouse.KeyDown:connect(function(key)
                if key:lower() == "e" then
                    if flying then
                        flying = false
                    else
                        flying = true
                        Fly()
                    end
                elseif key:lower() == "w" then
                    ctrl.f = 1
                elseif key:lower() == "s" then
                    ctrl.b = -1
                elseif key:lower() == "a" then
                    ctrl.l = -1
                elseif key:lower() == "d" then
                    ctrl.r = 1
                end
            end)
            mouse.KeyUp:connect(function(key)
                if key:lower() == "w" then
                    ctrl.f = 0
                elseif key:lower() == "s" then
                    ctrl.b = 0
                elseif key:lower() == "a" then
                    ctrl.l = 0
                elseif key:lower() == "d" then
                    ctrl.r = 0
                end
            end)
            Fly()
        end
    end))
end
```

I'm not sure why it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: are you using this ina localscript? This might have to be in starterpack for it to work because i only think game.Players.LocalPlayer only returns a player in starterpack work in a players backpack. Also can you post the code before the if statement so i can see if thats right. Is this script erroring?